# Proper way to move to another activity? Android Manifest Issue

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-activity

I was looking at some lint errors and notice that there are two ways to transition activities.

From what I learned from various internet sources I have always been assigning each activity in my manifest an intent-filter with an action name and then calling that with an intent to go to that activity.

However this has given me the: "Exported Activity does not require permission" lint error. Some have said this can be a weird issue and that it is better to go to (use the startActivity() method) by referring to the activity class. By calling the Class of the activity instead of an intent filter.

Can anyone attest to which way is better? However it does seem the way that does not prompt a lint error would be the better way...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended approach is that an `Activity` should not have a registered `<intent-filter>` section in the manifest unless it is meant to be used by external apps. An example of this would be for viewing a particular document mime-type using something like an `Intent` action `ACTION_VIEW`. This is is basically an implicit `Intent` action.

If your `Activity` classes are only meant to be used internally by your own app's components then they should only be started using expiclit `Intents` for example...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
```

In this case, the app component starting the `Activity` 'knows' what it wants to do and starts a specific `Activity` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a BroadcastReceiver to process the intents. It will in turn start your activities. From the Broadcast receiver do a startActivity().  So you use a filter on the  broadcast receiver gets the intent, but then the broadcast receiver will start the corresponding activity using startActivity.  So in this situation its a combination really, but requires you to broadcast the intent rather than targeting it by a classname.  If your app is simple you can just startActivity(intent) from another activity. But don't register filters on an Activity.  I know this answer is not a crowd favorite but its called loose coupling, or separation of concerns or something.

Comment: It's "not a crowd favorite" because it's pretty strange. I have been at this for over four years now, and I have never seen this done. It adds more overhead (double the IPC calls to start the activity) *and* will force you to keep creating new tasks (I think -- usually a `BroadcastReceiver` needs to create a new task when starting an activity, but I have never seen them used this way). It will also result in the exact same security warning that the OP is concerned about. And, to top it off, I'm not convinced that it materially loosens the coupling more than would some in-process Java.

Comment: But, if you have pointers to apps that are successfully using the technique, I'd be happy to take a peek at them.